# How to automatically run a program when I connect a phone to my computer?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, maven, csv

I am trying to import csv file from a phone to a database. 
I am using spring batch and it works with eclipse.

I want to execute this program automatically. So I have tried to create a jar file (using eclipse and then using maven) but it does not work.

I have done a lot of researches about this subject but there is nothing usefull for what I want to do.

My question is : can I execute this program automatically (for exemple when I connect my phone on my computer) ? And if it is possible, do you know how I could do this ?

Comment: "it does not work": can you be a _little_ more specific? What error are you having?

Comment: If the actual question is "how to automagically run a program when I connect X to Y" you should put that in the title instead of the problem you've already solved.

Comment: The error is "no main manifest attribute in jar".
But I have a main class which is declared in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier. I made it work by writing executable(.exe) file. It was containing simple windows commands along with the Java command to run that jar file(to trigger the job).After connecting a device, I would double click that file. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried but it does not work for me, I cannot run the .exe. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was the error using maven.

When I am using Eclipse to generate the jar file I have another problem.

I have a .bat with "java -jar .jar" and when I run it I have :

"A JNI error has occured"